# Android setStreamVolume for STREAM_RING doesn't always work while RINGING

Tags: android, volume, android-audiomanager

I am trying to do this simple App that allows the phone to ring but not to play a sound when receiving notifications under Android 4 (ICS). In order to do that I set the ring/notification stream to 0 (mute). When receiving a call I set the ring volume to max (p.e. 7) and then, on Idle, I turn it back to 0 (mute).

To do that I use this simple code.

```
public class ReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
   @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {      
      if ("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE".equals(intent.getAction()))
      {  String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);      
         AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
         {  amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);           
         }
         else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
         {  amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 7, 0);           
         }        
      }
   }  
}
```

The problem is that it sometime works and it sometime doesn't. I cannot find a reason. I call myself ten times and the ring sounds maybe 6. The other 4 were muted. strange??

I understand that my application could take "too long" to call setStreamVolume to 7 so maybe that is way sometimes gets on time (and sounds) and sometimes it is too late (so it doesn't sound) because the call already started with 0 volume. So, is there a way to restart the ringing sound? Could anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I must say you should  try giving your Broadcast Receiver high priority. which can be done like below

```
  <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
 </intent-filter>
```

refer the link >>
[Highest priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY)

It can/may solve your problem.

Comment: I also tried to play myself the default ring tone (using MediaPlayer). This works pretty well when android fails and don't play the ringing. But if it doesn't fail then both ringtones are heard at the same time with a bit overlapped so the result is terrible. I wish I knew how to stop the android ringing (in case it is on) and start mine by itself.

Comment: The following class is causing your issues : [Ringer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.2_r1/com/android/phone/Ringer.java#Ringer)  It returns if the ring volume is set to 0, if it gets in before you set the volume  to something other than 0, doom.