# Stopping ringtone

Tags: android, blacklist

I am trying to stop ringtone.
When the phone rings it plays a tone. I am trying to stop that sound 
depending on some factors, for example, caller in on a black list.

```
public class ReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {      
       if ("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE".equals(intent.getAction()))
       {  String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);      
          if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
          {  String Caller = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
             if(IsCallerInBlackList(Caller) == true)
                ----Stop the ringing here????---------
          }        
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) to stop ringtone as

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneManager;
ringtoneManager= new RingtoneManager(context);
ringtoneManager.stopPreviousRingtone();
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't stop it. Any extra hint?

Comment: try to set `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`
before `if ("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE".equals(intent.getAction()))` and if number is not black listed then make it `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);`

Comment: and make sure control is going inside if block by puting log.v messege

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to

1)   make phone into silent mode when you want to make ringtone off. by below statements.

```
 AudioManager aM = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 aM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

and then can again make ringtone mode to previous one when phone stopped ringing

Comment: Well, I made something like that before but it didn't work. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274105/android-setstreamvolume-for-stream-ring-doesnt-always-work-while-ringing

Comment: Have you tried making it into silent mode as i suggested.. I Hope it will work..Please give it a try